# Удаление записей из таблицы в Django

Tags: python, django

Мне нужно реализовать удаление определенных записей из таблицы в Django путём нажатия на ссылку(или кнопку) на странице под записью. Я не знаю как сделать, чтобы можно было не создавать отдельные шаблоны с формами для удаления, а удалять через один шаблон. Возможно ли такое?

```
<div class="col-5 offset-1">
                <h1>Информация</h1>

                {% for info in all_info %}

                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-9">
                            <b>Город:</b> {{ info.city }} <br>
                            <b>Температура:</b> {{ info.temp }} <sup>o</sup> <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-2 offset-1">
                            <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/{{ info.icon }}.png" alt="Фото погоды" class="img-thumbnail"><br>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">Удалить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
def index(request):
    API = 'token'

    cities = City.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        form.save()

    form = CityForm()

    all_cities = []
    for city in cities:

        url = f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city.name}&units=metric&appid={API}'

        response = requests.get(url).json()

        city_info = {
            'city': city.name,
            'temp': response['main']['temp'],
            'icon': response['weather'][0]['icon']
        }

        all_cities.append(city_info)

    context = {'all_info': all_cities, 'form':form}

    return render(request, 'weather/index.html', context)
```